# Error CS0029 Cannot implicity convert System.Collections.Generic.List, return not working

Tags: c#

My return is not working, error CS0029 is implying this:

`System.Collections.Generic.List<namesolution>` to `namesolution`
How can I make my return work?

This is my code:

```
    [Route("/getVeiculos")]
    public VeiculoModel getVeiculos()
    {
        List<VeiculoModel> list = new List<VeiculoModel>();            
        list.Add( new VeiculoModel {
            idVeiculo = 1,
            corVeiculo = "Verde",
            marcaVeiculo = "Volks",
            modeloVeiculo = "UP!",
            placaVeiculo = "AAA-8754"

        });

        list.Add(new VeiculoModel
        {
            idVeiculo = 2,
            corVeiculo = "Azul",
            marcaVeiculo = "Volks",
            modeloVeiculo = "Fusca",
            placaVeiculo = "CDV-8754"
        });

        return list;   
    }
enter code here
```

Comment: Your function expects to return an instance of `VeiculoModel` but you are returning `List<VeiculoModel>`.

Comment: Change `public VeiculoModel getVeiculos` to `public List<VeiculoModel> getVeiculos` if you want returning list of models.

Answer (score 1):

Your method getVeiculos() signature indicates you are trying to return a single instance of type VeiculoModel but the implementation is returning a list of VeiculoModel. Assuming the implementation is correct, update your method signature to:

```
public List<VeiculoModel> getVeiculos()
{
    // implementation...
}
```